# Where does Salesforce keep self-registration challenges to confirm identity?

Tags: apex, community, self-registration

We are using this method [initSelfRegistration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm#apex_System_UserManagement_initSelfRegistration) to allow people to self-register in our community.

```
String registrationAttemptId = System.UserManagement.initSelfRegistration(Auth.VerificationMethod.EMAIL, u);
```

So I have several questions:

1. Where does Salesforce store self-registration attempts?
2. Is there a limit on number of self-registration attempts per user, for org?
3. For how long is the a registration attempt is valid (basically, how long is the verification code sent by this method is valid)?

Comment: If by _self-registration attempt_ you really mean issuing a challenge to confirm an email address or a phone number, you might want to edit your question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to answer the questions, hope this helps

#### Where does Salesforce store self-registration attempts?

For login attempts by users who have already successfully self registered, their valid or failed identity verification, are tracked under **Setup > Identity Verification History**.

Note that according to this trailhead unit [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/identity-for-mobile-centric-customers/identity_mfi_clicks#Tdxn4tBK-heading12), if email is a field that must be filled upon registration, then a user cannot self register with an email that was already used.

In this case if a user tries to self register with an existing email, the user creation fails and verification attempt is not tracked under Identity Verification History.
But the system admin will be notified with a registration error "portal user already exists for contact".

#### Is there a limit on number of self-registration attempts per user, for org?

If self registration is based on existing identifier (email address or phone), then as mentioned there will be an error message and the system admin will be notified with a registration error "portal user already exists for contact".

When a user self-registers, the user consumes a license.
So the limit also depends on the number of External Identity licenses provisioned for the org.
More info [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_selfreg_page.htm&type=5)

If you are referring to the number of attempts a user can enter a valid verification code, could not find any article on this.

But per hour we can request a maximum of 5 verification code, refer to article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317627&type=1&mode=1)

#### How long is the verification code sent by this method is valid ?

As per salesforce documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activating_computer.htm&type=5) :

> Salesforce sends a verification code in an email to the address associated with your account. The code expires after 24 hours.